# Case Statement for order by clause with multiple columns sort

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I Write the following SQL query to get data order by some condition,

```
SELECT @NullCount = COUNT(1)
FROM @ServicesForBranch where SortValue IS NULL;

SELECT @ServiceCount = COUNT(1) 
FROM Service;

SELECT * FROM @tmp t

WHERE t.IsActive = 1 
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @NullCount = @ServiceCount THEN t.SortValue ELSE t.BranchServiceSortValue,t.Name END
```

But error is showing in this line `t.BranchServiceSortValue,t.Name` as

**`incorrect syntax near ','`**

What I wrote wrong here?

Comment: `CASE` expression returns one result.

Comment: @Sami Can u please provie answer or edit my query , pls

Comment: Your case statement is incorrect.In case statement, the else condition returns two columns (t.BranchServiceSortValue,t.Name)

Comment: @Sachith You need to write other `CASE` expressions as well.

Comment: If you want to order by both columns (t.BranchServiceSortValue,t.Name) so you need to close case statement then write second column.

Comment: @AakashSingh 1) It's an **expression** not a statement. 2) What does _"write second column"_ means here?

Comment: @Sami, Write t.Name outside from case

Comment: Nope, because the results will be sorted by `Name` even if `@NullCount <> @ServiceCount`, which is not what the OP want according to his code.

Answer (score 0):

Each `CASE` statement returns only 1 value so you need another one:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @NullCount = @ServiceCount THEN t.SortValue ELSE t.BranchServiceSortValue END,
CASE WHEN @NullCount <> @ServiceCount THEN t.Name END
```

but if `SortValue` is unique or you don't mind a secondary sorting on `Name` then you can simplify to this:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @NullCount = @ServiceCount THEN t.SortValue ELSE t.BranchServiceSortValue END,
t.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT @NullCount = COUNT(1)
FROM @ServicesForBranch 
where SortValue IS NULL;

SELECT @ServiceCount = COUNT(1) 
FROM Service;

SELECT * FROM @tmp t

WHERE t.IsActive = 1 
    ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN @NullCount = @ServiceCount THEN t.SortValue ELSE t.BranchServiceSortValue END),t.Name
```